# Ubuntu 12.10 install stuck at first step

Tags: installation, 12.10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 from a DVD-R disk, and everything is just fine until I get to the first window after clicking `Install Ubuntu` I checked the box `Download updates while installing` and also the `Install third-party software` box.

After clicking next, however, the install just hangs there. I've been waiting for over an hour now and all I see is the mouse cursor showing that it's `loading`.

What should I do to get past this? Thanks!

Comment: You should probably just hold the power button to turn the machine off, and then retry without checking any boxes.

Comment: I tried that, still stuck at the same spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the md5sum of your downloaded iso, (in windows use http://www.winmd5.com/), get the checksum to compare with from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes, if the sums are the same burn the iso on another dvd preferably on a regular dvd and try again. If the sums are not the same redownload ubuntu.

Comment: I re-burend the ISO to a DVD+R and it works perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who is still having this problem, i figured it out.
 for some reason the ubuntu LIVE system mounts and uses the swap located on the hard drive in 12.10 :/
here is how to fix it:
step 1: open gparted
step 2: locate the partition labeled "swap"
step 3: click "swap off"
step 4: re-try system installation